# Connection Fails while trying to insert data through a winform

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

[image]

When I'm executing this code "argument exception was unhanded" is popping up on my screen.
Can somebody assist me how to go about it?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The exception most probably comes from the connection string being invalid.

Comment: Argument in your case is one of the connection string properties, such as `Data source`, `password`, `user id`, etc. Post your connection string and we'll tell you what is wrong

Comment: Show me your app.config file...,

Comment: This is very bad programming !!

Comment: Do not use sql connection as a variable like this, very bad practice imo. Put it in a using statement!

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string doesn't seem to in correct format.

Make sure it is in proper format in app.config,

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="MyConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = yourDbName; Integrated Security = true" />
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

You can check http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: i figured it out but thanks so much .. actually the name of the database was incorrect ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString();
```

post your app.config file.your app.config file should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestData;Trusted_Connection=true;" />
 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```